# Database table design for dropdown list

Tags: html, mysql, drop-down-menu

I have a few drop down list in my HTML form and the drop down lists are populated from MySQL database. These drop down lists are totally independent. Do I need to create one table each for every drop down list? If not, how should I design a single table that contains all the dropdown list items? How can I design a good database structure?

I am not requesting for codes and thus I don't have sample codes too. I just need a screenshot of such a database or some advice how to do it.

Comment: A DB is not really necessary for that. A text or XML file would suffice.

Comment: I want user to be able to add and remove items from the list too. That is why I am going for database. Moreover I am not sure how can I do it with text, XML with HTML

Comment: it is quite simple an id field a(autoincrement and twi columsn atleat for value and text. that's the minimum, and if you need another attribute from option, that is not fix in the css file  you add a column. With javascript you can write that in a text file and read it of course again. If you want to save many lists in your table, you need of course a column to distinguish them

Comment: @nbk I didn't get exactly what you mean. Do you have an example for me to view?

Comment: I'd just have a separate table for each list

Comment: @Strawberry I think that is not a best practice althought it is the only way that i know too

Comment: Look at this example https://phppot.com/php/multi-select-dropdown-filter-in-php-with-database-search/

Comment: I know other ways. I'd do it that way.

Answer (score 1):

You can create only single Table with following structure,

```
CREATE TABLE MetaData (
    Id int,
    DropdownType varchar(255),
    YourDropdownValue1 varchar(255),
    YourDropdownValue2 varchar(255)
    ..
    ..
);
```

Eg City:-

```
insert into MetaData(DropdownType,YourDropdownValue1,YourDropdownValue2..) values('City','New York','NY')
insert into MetaData(DropdownType,YourDropdownValue1,YourDropdownValue2..) values('City','Paris','PR')
```

Eg Country:-

```
insert into MetaData(DropdownType,YourDropdownValue1,YourDropdownValue2..) values('Country','America','AM')
insert into MetaData(DropdownType,YourDropdownValue1,YourDropdownValue2..) values('Country','India','IN')
```

Note:- 
1) Keep Id as auto-increment primary key so that each time new value will be assigned.
2) Column-2 referred as Drop-down type so that you can mention type as per your requirement.

Hope this one will help to you.

Comment: Now I can see there are two rows where the dropdown type is City with different drop down values for city and two rows where the dropdown type is Country with differnt drop down values for country. Lets say if I want to show one drop down list for city by combining all the values in the different City rows, and one drop down list for Country by combining all the values in different Country rows, how should i do that?

Comment: You can use column name for filter like "select * from metadata where DropdownType ='City' and YourDropdownValue1(cityname) ='xyz'

Comment: What I mean is how to combine all those rows in order to show in one drop down list? With this way, there could be so many rows where City as the drop down type. What I need is to show all these city names in one drop down list and all these Country names in another drop down list etc.

Comment: I understood bro, why just you cant write a queries like ,`select * from metadata where DropdownType ='City'` so that query result you can use for city dropdown list,and `select * from metadata where DropdownType ='Country'` for country. is it making sense to you.?

Comment: By doing such a query, it will show only an item City or an item Country in the dropdown list. It will not fetch any city names or country names in the drop down list.

Comment: No boss ..it will fetch all the records belongs to City.just try by doing approach I mentioned in a answer.and upvote if you feel it's helps you.